# MySQL/MariaDB Optimizing a Two Table Full Text Search

Tags: mysql, mariadb, full-text-search, innodb, myisam

I'm trying to figure out how to optimize a full text search query which seems rather slow against two tables with around 2k entries, each. I'm running MariaDB 10.3.x. The two table query is orders of magnitude slower than one performed against a single table (e.g. 0.255 seconds vs. 0.03 seconds).

The goal is to search for a term in the relevant `uninet_articles` fields (`body`, `abstract`, `title`, `subtitle`) and also see if there are any occurrences of the term in the `uninet_tags` table, joining it as appropriate. Both tables have full text indexes. Here's the query:

```
    SELECT a.approve
    ,a.aid
    ,a.sid
    ,a.articleFormat
    ,title
    ,cachedTitle
    ,subtitle
    ,body
    ,abstract
    ,a.linkUrl
    ,a.byline
    ,a.poster
    ,a.allowComments
    ,a.allowRatings
    ,a.gmt
    ,a.lastModified
    ,a.modifier
    ,a.type
    ,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.gmt) AS DATETIME
    ,a.commentCount
    ,a.ratingCount
    ,a.ratingDetails
    ,(MATCH(a.body, a.title, a.subtitle, a.abstract) AGAINST('OS X' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) + MATCH(tags.name) AGAINST('OS X' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)) AS relevanceScore
    ,a.readCount
FROM uninet_articles a
LEFT JOIN uninet_tags AS tags ON a.aid = tags.paid
    AND MATCH(tags.name) AGAINST('OS X' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
WHERE MATCH(a.body, a.title, a.subtitle, a.abstract) AGAINST('OS X' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
    OR tags.tid
    AND a.type = 'article'
    AND `approve` != '0'
ORDER BY `approve` DESC
    ,`gmt` DESC LIMIT 0
    ,10
```

I was able to cut the query time by 25% when I upgraded to the current version of MariaDB. I've tried MyISAM and InnoDB -- InnoDB seems to perform about 50% worse than MyISAM. Aria seems to be ever slightly faster than MyISAM, but not significantly so.

This leads me to two questions: first, is there a way to optimize the query to make it faster so that when I scale up the data in the table it is semi-acceptable? Second, is there a way to optimize the query for InnoDB, so I can go ahead and make the leap to a safer database system?

Comment: Can you clarify if "tags.name" contains a list of tags (in one row), or if it is a single string? (And if not, can you make it this way, and if not, why not?) Then the best way to optimize a fulltext search would be to not use the fulltext search at all, but e.g. `tags.name = 'OS X'`.

Comment: @Solarflare `Tags.name` contains a single tag per row. That makes sense re: skipping the full text search. I kind of liked the idea that full text would match 'Mac OS X' and 'OS X', giving a more flexible search. Perhaps there's a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Multiple FT tests**

`MATCH` likes to be *first*.  But another `MATCH` cannot also be "first".

`OR` also hurts performance terribly.

So, let's separate them:

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE MATCH(tags.name) AGAINST('OS X' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT ...
    WHERE MATCH(a. ...) AGAINST('OS X' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT ...
    WHERE tags.tid
```

Then use that as a 'derived' table to do the rest of the work:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( the-above-union ) AS u
    ....
```

**Definition of "word"**

Also, the space *will not* work inside a "word" in a `FULLTEXT` search.

**Other issues**

Hmmm... Is `tags.tid` a boolean?  Perhaps you need to test that against something?

Comment: That looks really intriguing as a way to untangle my mess. Thank you! (I should have used a better example than 'OS X' in all this...) As to `tags.tid`, it is an unique identifier for the tag row. I was simply using it to see if the join was successful in coming up with a match or not.

Comment: @TimothyR.Butler - yes, but the `OR` messed up any chance of "optimizing".

Comment: tid can potentially be ignored completely. Basically, all I want to do is return the row in `uninet_articles` that either has a match within itself (your second query) or to which `a.aid=tags.paid` is true and there's a match in the corresponding `tags.name`.  Is the equivalent of `a.aid=tags.paid` present in the UNION function somehow?

Comment: @TimothyR.Butler - That will have to be handled in one of my 3 Selects.  And the `LEFT JOIN` becomes `JOIN`.  Write out each Select as if you only needed to do one of the Matches.